# opencart Add to cart in category page not adding item to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

I am trying to add items from category page. But it is taking me to next product page rather then adding such product into the cart. But same functionality is working ok in product page.

To find the solution i have added

```
 to check what array i am getting. After adding it such functionality of add to cart in category page was working. I am a bit confuse what to do with that. Kindly help or advice. Following is the code for Add-to-Cart button in category.tpl file.
```

`<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, even though I know nothing about opencart i quickly checked the demo.
There seem to be some category items that work to be added as expected:

```js
POST http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add
 
200 OK

{"success":"Success: You have added <a href=\"http:\/\/demo.opencart.com\/index.php?route=product\/product
&amp;product_id=41\">iMac<\/a> to your <a href=\"http:\/\/demo.opencart.com\/index.php?route=checkout
\/cart\">shopping cart<\/a>!","total":"2 item(s) - $244.00"}
```

Other ones return some kind of form error:

```js
POST http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add
 
{"error":{"option":{"218":"Radio required!","223":"Checkbox required!","208":"Text required!","217":"Select
 required!","209":"Textarea required!","222":"File required!","219":"Date required!","221":"Time required
!","220":"Date &amp; Time required!"}},"redirect":"http:\/\/demo.opencart.com\/index.php?route=product
\/product&product_id=42"}
```

And instead of showing a decent error message, a redirect url is sent along. Seems that that is the one you then are redirected to. Seems like intended behaviour of the code to hide that an error has happened.

Maybe that helps you to narrow down the bug. Good luck.

Comment: no Luba, if you can check at www.opencart.com, their demo is also not adding product into cart which is in header portion. category page add to cart take you to single product just like i've clicked the <a> tag

Comment: you are right in product page it managed with if check box, etc are enable then add their values. here its just add to cart with no if condition. let me try. thanks for your help. :)

Comment: you are right. it solved the mi-story. I remove all the checks, inputs, extra features which you have added in your reply. all of sudden that link start adding products because it has only input of number of products and add to cart. thanks again